# Game engines and LWJGL questions

Tags: java, game-engine, lwjgl

A question regarding 3D, in order to create a FPS, do you have to use a 3D engine or is it possible to create it using a library? What exactly is a Game Engine?

When you "code" for a game engine, what is it doing with your code? When you code using a library, are you "creating" your own game engine? Can you use LWJGL to create a full FPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do you have to use a 3D engine or is it possible to create it using a library?

I'm not sure I get what you mean. Though basically when creating a 3D application, you would usually either use [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) or [DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX) both of them is an API for 2D & 3D rendering. Those aren't 3D engines, but simply the tools for rendering 3D (and 2D). So now you can use one of those and create a 3D engine.

> What exactly is a Game Engine?

Basically a Game Engine is a piece of software which runs and controls everything within a game. Most game engines are written in C and C++, though you can of course use any language you want.

> When you "code" for a game engine, what is it doing with your code?

When you want to program a game engine, then you basically can do two things.

1. Create a full game engine which can do basically all the things you would need. Like loading 3D models, perform lighting, etc.
2. Create a game engine based on a game idea. What I mean by that is, when you have the main game idea, then you can create a game engine for that specific game. Thereby if the game doesn't need any lighting, then you of course don't have to write all the code for performing lighting.

> When you code using a library, are you "creating" your own game engine?

Well you don't need to use any extra libraries to create a game engine. The game engine is simply what makes your/the game run. Though you would of course use some sort of graphics rendering API like OpenGL, DirectX, etc. But basically you don't have to.

> Can you use LWJGL to create a full FPS?

LWJGL like JOGL is simply a Java OpenGL Wrapper, and using OpenGL you can create any kind of 3D application you want. If you have the skills you could probably create something like Crysis, *though I might chose to use C++ or C, instead of Java for creating something huge and advanced as Crysis, though it is possible.*

So yes using LWJGL you could easily create any kind of 3D and/or 2D game you want to.